# joint probability of two normal variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

let's say I have two random variables $$ X\sim Normal(1,\frac{2}{N_1})$$
$$Y\sim Normal(1,\frac{2}{N_2} )$$

Now if $$P(X \ge\lambda_1 ) = P(Y \ge \lambda)$$
Then is it correct to say that: 
$$P(X \lt \lambda_1,Y \ge \lambda_2)=P(Y \lt \lambda, Y \ge \lambda_2)  $$

since $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda \gt 0, N_2 \gt N_1 \gt 0. $

please advise
**Update**:
So since they are not equal then I can write :
$$P(X \lt \lambda_1,Y \ge \lambda_2)=P(Y \lt \lambda, Y \ge \lambda_2) +\alpha $$
How can I find some information about $\alpha$ knowning that 
$$ Y= aX + Z $$
while $Z$ is another normal RV ( Independent from X)with mean 1 and variance $\frac{1}{N_2-N_1}$
Any help!?

Comment: it seems that there is a typo in the variance argument of the distribution of $X$ and $Y$. Remember that the way to use `\frac` is `\frac{numerator}{denominator}`.

Answer (score 2):

No.
Note that if $\lambda<\lambda_2$ then the RHS is necessarily zero, being the probability of a contradiction, whereas the LHS is not zero.